# TFS Build without solution file

Tags: msbuild, build, solution

We use TFS 2008 server for our builds.

I need to create a build from a non Visual Studio project without solution file (only make files for custom compiler). But Build Wizard doesn't allow me create build project file without solution.

Is is posible to create TFS build for such project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have either a solution or project defined.  What you can do is inside the .proj file create a custom task to handle your scenario.

I would need to better understand what you needed done in order to provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. I already resolved this by creating my custom build proj file and assigned it to build by VS.

Comment: @RomanKuzyk I have a similar solution where I want to copy just the HTML files produced by our Front end team. There is no solution file or proj file. There are using Git repository in TFS. What will be the best option? Thanks